# Convolutional neural network debugging

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks

Im trying to implement CNN for small images classification (36x36x1) (grayscale). I've checked every forward/backward pass function on small example, and still my cnn is not doin any progress on training. Tests were done on learning rate [0.001 - 0.01].
Network structure:
Conv -> Relu -> Conv -> Relu -> MaxPooling -> Conv -> Relu -> Conv -> Relu -> MaxPooling -> Flattening -> sigmoid -> Fully connected -> sigmoid ->Fully connected -> softmax

Is there a mistake in forwardPass/ backwardPass function?

```
    def forwardPass(self, X):
    """
        :param X:   batch of images (Input value of entire convolutional neural network)
                    image.shape = (m,i,i,c) - c is number of channels
                    for current task, first input c = 1 (grayscale)
                    example: for RGB c = 3
                    m - batch size
                    X.shape M x I x I x C

        :return :   touple(Z, inValues)
                    Z - estimated probability of every class
                    Z.shape M x K x 1


    """

    W = self.weights

    inValues = {
        'conv': [],
        'fullyconnect': [],
        'mask' : [],
        'pooling' : [],
        'flatten' : [],
        'sigmoid' : [],
        'relu' : []
    }

    """
        Current structure:
        Conv -> Relu -> Conv -> Relu -> MaxPooling -> Conv -> Relu -> Conv -> Relu -> MaxPooling -> Flattening -> 
        -> sigmoid -> Fully connected -> sigmoid ->Fully connected -> softmax
    """



    inValues['conv'].append(X)
    Z = self.convolution_layer(X, W['conv'][0]);z = Z

    inValues['relu'].append(z)
    Z = self.relu(z);z =Z

    inValues['conv'].append(z)
    Z = self.convolution_layer(z, W['conv'][1]);z = Z


    inValues['relu'].append(z)
    Z = self.relu(z);z =Z


    inValues['pooling'].append(z)
    Z, mask = self.max_pooling(z);z = Z
    inValues['mask'].append(mask)



    inValues['conv'].append(z)
    Z = self.convolution_layer(z, W['conv'][2]);z = Z

    inValues['relu'].append(z)
    Z = self.relu(z);z = Z

    inValues['conv'].append(z)
    Z = self.convolution_layer(z, W['conv'][3]);z = Z

    inValues['relu'].append(z)
    Z = self.relu(z);z = Z

    inValues['pooling'].append(z)
    Z, mask = self.max_pooling(z);z = Z
    inValues['mask'].append(mask)


    inValues['flatten'].append(z)
    Z = self.flattening(z);z = Z


    inValues['sigmoid'].append(z)
    Z = self.sigmoid(z); z = Z


    inValues['fullyconnect'].append(z)
    Z = self.fullyConnected_layer(z, W['fullyconnect'][0]); z = Z


    #dropout here later

    inValues['sigmoid'].append(z)
    Z = self.sigmoid(z); z = Z


    inValues['fullyconnect'].append(z)
    Z = self.fullyConnected_layer(z, W['fullyconnect'][1]);z = Z


    Z = self.softmax(z)


    return Z, inValues
```

Backpropagation:

```
 def backwardPass(self, y, Y, inValues):

    """

    :param Y: estimated probability of all K classes
                ( Y.shape = M x K x 1 )
    :param y: True labels for current
                M x K x 1
    :param inValues: Dictionary with input values of conv/ff layers
                     example: inValues['conv'][1] - Values encountered during feedForward on input of Conv layer with index 1
    :return:  Gradient of weights in respect to L
    """

    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
    W = self.weights

    G = {
        'conv' : [],
        'fullyconnect' : []
    }


    Z = self.softmax_backward(Y, y); z = Z



    Z, dW, dB = self.fullyConnected_layer_backward(z, W['fullyconnect'][1],inValues['fullyconnect'][1]);z = Z
    weight = {
        'W': dW,
        'B': dB
    }
    G['fullyconnect'].append(weight)



    Z = self.sigmoid_deriv(z, inValues['sigmoid'][1]); z = Z

    Z, dW, dB = self.fullyConnected_layer_backward(z, W['fullyconnect'][0],inValues['fullyconnect'][0]);z = Z;
    weight = {
        'W': dW,
        'B': dB
    }
    G['fullyconnect'].append(weight)


    Z = self.sigmoid_deriv(z, inValues['sigmoid'][0]);z=Z


    Z = self.flattening_backward(z, inValues['flatten'][0]); z = Z


    Z = self.max_pooling_backward(z,inValues['mask'][1]); z = Z


    Z = z * self.relu(inValues['relu'][3], deriv=True); z = Z

    Z, dW, dB = self.convolution_layer_backward(z, W['conv'][3],inValues['conv'][3]); z = Z
    weight = {
        'W': dW,
        'B': dB
    }
    G['conv'].append(weight)

    Z = z * self.relu(inValues['relu'][2], deriv=True);z = Z


    Z, dW, dB = self.convolution_layer_backward(z, W['conv'][2],inValues['conv'][2]); z = Z
    weight = {
        'W': dW,
        'B': dB
    }
    G['conv'].append(weight)


    Z = self.max_pooling_backward(z,inValues['mask'][0]);z = Z


    Z = z * self.relu(inValues['relu'][1], deriv=True);z = Z

    Z, dW, dB = self.convolution_layer_backward(z, W['conv'][1],inValues['conv'][1]); z = Z
    weight = {
        'W': dW,
        'B': dB
    }
    G['conv'].append(weight)

    Z = z * self.relu(inValues['relu'][0], deriv=True);z = Z

    Z, dW, dB = self.convolution_layer_backward(z, W['conv'][0],inValues['conv'][0]); z = Z
    weight = {
        'W': dW,
        'B': dB
    }
    G['conv'].append(weight)

    G['conv'].reverse()
    G['fullyconnect'].reverse()

    return G
```

update:

```
    def update(self, alfa, W, G):

    W['fullyconnect'][0]['W'] -= alfa * np.sum(G['fullyconnect'][0]['W'],axis=0)
    W['fullyconnect'][1]['W'] -= alfa * np.sum(G['fullyconnect'][1]['W'],axis=0)
    W['fullyconnect'][0]['B'] -= alfa * np.sum(G['fullyconnect'][0]['B'],axis=0)
    W['fullyconnect'][1]['B'] -= alfa * np.sum(G['fullyconnect'][1]['B'],axis=0)

    W['conv'][0]['W'] -= alfa * np.sum(G['conv'][0]['W'],axis=0)
    W['conv'][1]['W'] -= alfa * np.sum(G['conv'][1]['W'],axis=0)
    W['conv'][2]['W'] -= alfa * np.sum(G['conv'][2]['W'],axis=0)
    W['conv'][3]['W'] -= alfa * np.sum(G['conv'][3]['W'],axis=0)
    W['conv'][0]['B'] -= alfa * np.sum(G['conv'][0]['B'],axis=0)
    W['conv'][1]['B'] -= alfa * np.sum(G['conv'][1]['B'],axis=0)
    W['conv'][2]['B'] -= alfa * np.sum(G['conv'][2]['B'],axis=0)
    W['conv'][3]['B'] -= alfa * np.sum(G['conv'][3]['B'],axis=0)

    return W
```

Comment: Can you show what error you're facing? Does the model compile? I mean, does it even 'start' training, or do you face matrix dimensionality issues?